# Async spring security WebFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

How can I get rid of block in WebFilter with SecurityContextHolder. I tried to put auth setting in Mono's doOnSuccess(...) and thenEmpty(...), but it was never invoked.

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
    long internalId = Long.parseLong(headers.get(INTERNAL_ID_HEADER).get(0));
    String email = headers.get(EMAIL_HEADER).get(0);

    Mono<User> userMono = Mono.just(internalId)
            .flatMap(userRepository::findById)
            .switchIfEmpty(userRepository.save(new User().setId(internalId)
                            .setFirstName(getFirstName(email))
                            .setLastName(getLastName(email))
                            .setEmail(email)
                    )
            );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userMono.block());

    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use blocking infrastructure from Spring Security.
If I remember correctly, `SecurityContextHolder` is `ThreadLocal`-based; that approach won't work in a reactive environmenet where a given request **is not handled on a single thread**.

You might want to take a look at the [upcoming WebFlux support in Spring Security](https://spring.io/blog/2017/06/16/spring-security-5-0-0-m2-released).

Comment: So can you, please, show me an approach, how can I use UserDetailsRepository for users without password? (application is placed behind web server, which uses SSO and set required headers)

Comment: Did you try the approach explained in the blog post I listed? (using EnableWebFluxSecurity and providing your `UserDetailsRepository`? Once done, pleas open a new SO question and show what you've tried.

Comment: How can I use `UserDetailsRepository` for users without passwords, authorizing using header value?